# SSRS - Global Parameter

Tags: asp.net, .net, reporting-services

I have few different reports on a custom website. There is a menubar on top where one of the tab is Reports. If I hover over that tab, I can see list of reports underneath it. There is a separate "Filter" button upon clicking pops up a window to set all parameters and then click Generate Report to view report based on the parameter selection (default parameters will generate report too so you do NOT have to do this to view the report the first time). Now, I go from one report to another from menubar. I have to go through the same process of selection parameters (if I want to change from default values) and filter data for the 2nd report.

Is there a way to set parameter for one report, go to menubar/reports tab and select another report where the parameter values are same as previous report?

Thank you

---

Well, "I" don't necessarily maintain the custom website. If I go into the ReportServer and view the reports, I have all the parameter listed on top of the rendered report. But, this website has a popup window (javascript maybe??) where you have all the parameter and drop down list with values of each parameter... You click on a button below the menu bar that says 'Filters" and comes open this window where you can select values of each parameter/hierarchy and click on "Generate" and report will refresh with filtered data. But, when I go to a different report from menubar, the parameter resets to some default values...I want those values to be same as values from the previously generated report...does that help?

Comment: Do you maintain the "custom website"? If it's using a ReportViewer you could perhaps make the parameter hidden, create your own DropDownList for the parameter, and pass it to a report in code behind. That way you can keep it selected, even if the user switches reports.